# Efficient usage of a c++11 shared_ptr in an asset manager

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm working on a game (and my own custom engine). I have quite a few assets (textures, skeletal animations, etc.) that are used by multiple models and therefore get loaded multiple times.

At first, my ambitions were smaller, game simpler and I could live with a little duplication, so `shared_ptr` which took care of resource cleanup once the last instance was gone seemed like a good idea. As my game grew, more and more resources got loaded multiple times and all the OpenGL state changing slowed the performance down to a crawl. To solve this problem, I decided to write an asset manager class.

I'm using an `unordered_map` to store a path to file in `std::string` and c++11's `shared_ptr` pointing to the actual loaded asset. If the file is already loaded, I return the pointer, if not, I call the appropriate `Loader` class. Plain and simple.

Unfortunately, I can't say the same about removal. One copy of the pointer remains in the `unordered_map`. Currently, I iterate through the entire map and perform `.unique()` checks every frame. Those pointers that turn out to be unique, get removed from the map, destroying the last copy and forcing the destructor run and do the cleanup.

Iterating through hundreds or thousands of objects is not the most efficient thing to do. (it's not a premature optimization, I am in optimization stage now) Is it possible to somehow override the shared pointer functionality? For example, add an "onLastRemains" event somehow? Maybe I should iterate through part of the `unordered_map` every frame (by bucket)? Some other way?

I know, I could try to write my own reference counted asset implementation, but all current code I have assumes that assets are shared pointers. Besides, shared pointers are excellent at what they do, so why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of storing `shared_ptr`s in the asset manager's `map`(see below, use a regular map), store `weak_ptr`s. When you construct a new asset, create a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter which calls a function in the asset manager which tells it to remove this pointer from it's map. The custom deleter should contain the iterator into the map of this asset and supply that iterator when telling the asset manager to delete it's element from the map. The reason a `weak_ptr` is used in the map is that any subsequent requests for this element can still be given a `shared_ptr` (because you can make one from a `weak_ptr`) but the asset manager doesn't actually have ownership of the asset and the custom deleter strategy will work.

Edit: It was noted below the above technique only works if you use a `std::map` not a `std::unordered_map`. My recommendation would be to still do this, and switch to a regular map.

Comment: `unordered_map` iterators may be invalidated by insertion.  So it is not safe to store iterators into an `unordered_map` which may have objects added to it later.  It would be safe for `std::map` though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That wouldn't give you the ability to erase the element without incurring a lookup cost though.

Comment: The pointers are enough to delete zero the weak_ptr, deferring the removal.

Comment: @Deduplicator: What benefit would that be?

Comment: What is the point of erasing an expired element from the map? I'd assume that the overhead of the weak pointer is negligible. Otherwise, using the weak/shared combination is exactly what I would do. There is one pitfall though: You must make sure to not prematurely discard things from your cache, e.g. when a button blinks between two states you must keep both in memory. If you can't do that, using a timestamp to detect stale elements and maybe only checking a part of the whole map on each turn could be an alternative.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The overhead of the `weak_ptr` is negligible, except when the pointee itself is large and was constructed by `make_shared`. Since `make_shared` uses a single memory allocation for the pointee and the control block, the entire allocation has to hang around until the last `weak_ptr` goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `std::unique_ptr` in your `unordered_map` of assets.

Expose a `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that looks up said pointer in the `unordered_map`, and either deletes it, or moves it to a second container "to be deleted later".  Remember, `std::shared_ptr` does **not** have to actually own the data in question!  The deleter can do any arbitrary action, and can even be stateful.

This lets you keep O(1) lookups for your assets, bunch cleanup (if you want to) instead of doing cleanup in the middle of other scenes.

You can even support temporary 0 reference count without deleting as follows:

Create a `std::make_shared` in the `unordered_map` of assets.

Expose custom `std::shared_ptr`.  These hold a raw `T*` in the data, and the deleter holds a copy of the `std::shared_ptr` in the asset map.  It "deletes" itself by storing the name (which it also holds) into a central "to be deleted" list.

Then go over said "to be deleted" list and check if they are indeed `unique()` -- if not, it means someone else in the meantime has spawned one of the "child" `std::shared_ptr< T*, std::function<void(T*)>>`s.

The only downside to this is that the type of exposed `std::shared_ptr` is no longer a simple `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
shared_ptr<assed> get_asset(string path) {
  static map<string, weak_ptr<asset>> cache;

  auto ap = cache[path].lock();
  if(!ap) cache[path] = ap = load_asset(path);
  return ap;
}
```